# Download file from Amazon S3 using the AWS SDK for Java across accounts

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to download a file from my Amazon S3 bucket. The catch here is that the Amazon S3 bucket is in a different account. I believe I have the right permissions because ,

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/path/img.JPG ./
```

This is working.

But while performing the same operation from the Java SDK, it throws `(Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey;`

```
def downloadfile(amazonS3Client: AmazonS3, fileKeyName: String): Boolean = {
    try {
      amazonS3Client.getObject("bucketname", fileKeyName)
      true
    } catch {
      case ex: Exception => print(ex); false
    }
  }
```

I am using the default client (so the credentials should be same as cli) and I am calling this function like ,

```
downloadFile(AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient(), "path/img.JPG")
```

also tried,

```
downloadFile(AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient(), "img.JPG")
```

Comment: Amazon provides this doc for this use case -- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/

Comment: We have created the policy using the same doc. Any idea why cli is working and not the sdk code ?

Answer (score 0):

I checked with the SDK team and they pointed me to this doc.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/setting-up-cross-account-amazon-s3-access-with-s3-access-points/